# TabBar with Phonegap not working on every page

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I'm using PhoneGap with the NativeControls/TabBar plugin and it's working for the first page. However, when I press to navigate to a different page the plugin stops being effective.

On the `index.html` page:

```
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
            nativeControls = window.plugins.nativeControls;
            nativeControls.createTabBar();              
            console.log("TabBar initiated");
            nativeControls.createTabBarItem(
              "about",
              "About",
              "/www/img/20-gear2.png",
              {"onSelect": function() {
                window.location.href="about.html";
              }}
            );
            nativeControls.createTabBarItem(
              "guide",
              "Guide",
              "/www/img/76-baby.png",
              {"onSelect": function() {
                window.location.href="grid.html";
              }}
            );
            nativeControls.createTabBarItem(
              "ideas",
              "Ideas",
              "/www/img/27-planet.png",
              {"onSelect": function() {
                window.location.href="ideas.html";
              }}
            );
            nativeControls.showTabBar();
            nativeControls.showTabBarItems("about", "guide", "ideas");
        }, false)
    </script>
```

Pressing any of the buttons takes it to the corresponding HTML page with the correct tab selected. However, on this page, none of the tabs continue to work - pressing the tab button simply highlights it but doesn't relocate the view to the page.

I have tried pasting this same script onto the header of the other pages but there is no result there either.

Comment: I would love to know the answer to this!

Answer (score 0):

A previous solution I have used for this was to load all the content via AJAX rather than loading additional .html pages. I've included some snippets below:

In index.html, I have a DIV designated to receive the HTML for each page

```
<div id="ajaxCont"> </div>
```

Also within index.html, I have the following function declared:

```
function loadPage(url, onleave, onenter, title) {                               

   // If onleave function specified
   if (onleave) {
      onleave();
   }

   var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

   // Callback function when XMLHttpRequest is ready
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
      if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
         if (xmlhttp.status == 200 || xmlhttp.status == 0) {
            document.getElementById('ajaxCont').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

            // If onenter function specified
            if (onenter) {
                onenter();
            }
         }else {
            document.getElementById('ajaxCont').innerHTML = "Error loading page " + url;
         }
      }
   };

   xmlhttp.open("GET", url , true);
   xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Then, each tabbar item can be created like so:

```
tabBar.createItem("contact", "Contact", "/www/img/734-chat.png", {
    onSelect: function() {
       loadPage("contact.html", null, null, "Contact");
    }
});
```